# How to make docker container ls -f name filter by exact name?

Tags: docker

`docker container ls -f name=foo` returns all containers which have names that contain *foo*. This means it also return a container named `foobar`, for example. How can I filter for all the containers named exactly *foo*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's only one container named exactly "foo", so use:

```
$ docker container inspect foo
```

instead, and you can format the output to get whatever data you need from that. E.g. to show the current status and image:

```
$ docker container inspect foo -f '{{.State.Status}} {{.Config.Image}}'
running foo_image:latest
```

---

From the comments, to see if the container "foo" exists, you can use:

```
if docker container inspect foo >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "container exists"
else
  echo "container does not exit"
fi
```

Comment: This is a great idea when the container exists, in my case I'm trying to find out whether the container exists.

Comment: If it doesn't exist, the return code from the inspect is non-zero. You can catch that with an if.

Answer (score 33):

```
docker container ls -f name=^foo$
```

It can be achieved by using a regular expression. The caret `^` matches the exact start of the name and the dollar `$` matches the end.

Comment: With  this, I just get a syntax error.

Comment: on fish shell you might have to put the pattern in quotes - `docker container ls -f name='^foo$'`